# Tensorflow Sliding Window Transformation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do sliding window transformation for RNN application using Tensorflow.

For a window size of 4, with Tensorflow simple reshaping, we can transform the following tensor:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

to:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
```

But I want it to be with a stride of 1 like the following tensor:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],...,[17,18,19,20]]
```

With Tensorflow tiling I can get:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
```

I think with some transformation of that I can get what I want. Do you have any thoughts ?

My code to generate the above tiling result is a simple as follows. But each element will be a 1D tensor representing a bottleneck (feature vector from CNN) instead of a number in my example above.

```
model.logits, model.end_points = inception_v3.inception_v3(model.X_Norm, num_classes=nbrOfOutputNeurons, is_training=is_training)
model.bottleneck = slim.flatten(model.end_points['PreLogits']) # The ouput before FC

x = tf.reshape(model.bottleneck, [1, -1, bottleneck_tensor_size])
x = tf.tile(x, [rnn_time_steps, 1, 1])
```

Comment: `s=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]` and `d = [s[i:i+4]  for i in range(len(s)) if len(s[i:i+4])> 3]`

Comment: @Hesham what code are you currently using to generate these outputs you're showing?

Comment: @dantiston I've edited my question.

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks. But doing it with Pyhton lists is simple, the question is how to represent this on TF graph ?

Answer (score 8):

`tf.map_fn` is the tensorflow version of `map`

```
x = tf.range(1, 21, dtype=tf.int32)
xm = tf.map_fn(lambda i: x[i:i+4], tf.range(20-4+1), dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  x, xm = session.run([x, xm])
  print(x)
  print(xm)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
    from tensorflow.python.ops.signal import shape_ops
    framed_signals = shape_ops.frame(signal, win_len, win_step)
```