# Tensorflow sliding window transformation over large data

Tags: tensorflow, large-data, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to feed my model with stride-1 windows from a very long data sequence (tens of millions of entries). This is similar to the aim presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718649/tensorflow-sliding-window-transformation) thread, only that my data sequence may contain several features to begin with, so the final number of features is n_features * window_size. i.e. with two original features and a window size of 3, this would mean transforming this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

to:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I was trying to use slicing with map_fn or Dataset.map, applied to a  sequence of indices (per the answer in the above-mentioned thread), as in:

```
    ti = tf.range(data.shape[0] - window_size)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ti, labels))

    def get_window(l, label):
         wnd = tf.reshape(data_tensor[l:(l + window_size), :], (-1, window_size * n_features))
         wnd = tf.squeeze(wnd)
         return (wnd, label)

    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(get_window)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    ...
```

This is working in principle, but the training is extremely slow, with minimal GPU utilization (1-5%, probably in part because the mapping is done in the CPU).

When trying to do the same with tf.map_fn, the graph building becomes very lengthy, with tremendous memory utilization.

Another option I was trying is to transform all of the data in advance before I load it in Tensorflow. This works much faster (even when considering the pre-processing time, I wonder why - shouldn't it be the same operation as the mapping during training?) but is very inefficient in terms of memory and storage, as the data becomes window_size-fold larger. That is a deal-breaker for my large datasets.
I thought about splitting these transformed bloated datasets into several files ("hyper-batches") and go through them in sequence for each epoch, but this seems very inefficient and I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this simple transformation.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are first mapping and *then* batching?  It seems that you would want to first draw a minibatch and only after that apply the map.

Comment: I actually tried both ways and the result was almost identical in terms of computation time. I figured that the mapping is actually happening only when computing the gradients for a specific minibatch. But I'm not sure I fully understand how Dataset.map works, and how is it different from using tf.map_fn on the source tensor before creating a dataset from it (with regards to the time the actual mapping takes place).

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Looking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py and the class MapDataset, `Dataset.map` just adds the map function onto the graph (as seems to be the right/best thing to do). I'm surprised then that it causes a big slow-down; do you have an unmapped version that is much faster?

Comment: Yes. When pre-transforming the data and just removing the mapping from the graph building, the training becomes an order of magnitude faster, with ~90% GPU utilization. Could it be the way I implement get_window?